# Concatenation with %keyword in mini-panels

Tags: drupal-7

Someone posted another question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195860/how-does-one-concatenate-fields-in-title-field-in-panels-pages but its not working for me.

I need to concatenate a custom text as prefix with %node:field_city_title keyword while adding a node field in mini-panels.

I tried with `Event in %node:field_city_title` , `Event in%node:field_city_title` and searched a lot but nothing works for me.

[image]

If you any idea, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out but not sure either it's a standard way or not but I believe override title field is not accepted "prefix or postfix" for `%keyword` like mentioned in the question.

**Solution**

1) Removed tag h1 from the attached image in the question.

2) Created new tpl named as `panels-pane--event-node-title.tpl.php` and added some code in it

```
<div class="pane-content">
  <?php if ($title): ?>
  <h1> <?php print $title; ?> </h1>
  <?php else : ?>
    // Here we can set any prefix or postfix within the tag
    <h1> Event in <?php print render($content); ?> </h1>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**$content** variable will get content of the field along with its all settings (ID, class, tag etc.)

Hope, this will help someone. Thanks